# Build a small V8 shared lib on linux?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I tried building V8 following instruction from [Hellow world V8](https://v8.dev/docs/embed)
However the lib libv8_monolith.a generted is of 28 MB size.
I see framework like Deno which do use V8 underneath is of roughly around only 12 MB.
So how do I build a V8 shared lib of smaller size ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try (on any C/C++ application) is to run `strip` on the final binary.

Another thing you could consider is to compile V8 without i18n support (`v8_enable_i18n_support = false` is the GN arg for that). Many features of the built-in `Intl` object as well as RegExp unicode support will then not work properly, but depending on your use case that might be okay, and it saves the dependency on ICU which is several megabytes.